# How to use the rewrite command in coq for inner subexpressions?

Tags: logic, coq, induction

I have a lemma telling that addition commutes:

```
Lemma commute: for all x y, add x y = add y x.
```

Now in my goal, I am trying to prove that:

`add (add x (S y)) z = add x (S (add y z))`

I would like to use my lemma to rewrite the inner add on the left

`add x (S y)` to `add (S y) x`.

However, the command `rewrite commute` instead rewrites the outer add:

`add (add x (S y)) z` to `add z (add x (S y))`.

**Question: how to use commute for rewriting inner subexpressions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can precise which arguments you want for your lemma with :

```
rewrite commute with (x := x)(y :=(S y)).
```

But it is even more common to apply it like a function with :

```
rewrite (commute x (S y)).
```

If one of the specified arguments is obvious, you can avoid mentionning it in the first case, or put an underscore in the second, which would give here :

```
rewrite commute with (y :=(S y)).
```

and

```
rewrite (commute _ (S y)).
```